# Stop an operation without stopping the module in python

Tags: python, exception, module

Well, I have made a module that allows you to copy a file to a directory easier. Now, I also have some "try's" and "except's" in there to make sure it doesn't fail in the big messy way and doesn't close the terminal, but I also want it to display different error messages when a wrong string or variable is put in, and end the module, but not the...if I may say, Terminal running it, so I did this:

```
def copy():
    import shutil
    import os
    try:
        cpy = input("CMD>>> Name of file(with extension): ")
        open(cpy, "r")
    except:
        print("ERROR>>> 02x00 No such file")
    try:
        dri = input("CMD>>> Name of Directory: ")
        os.chdir(dri)
        os.chdir("..")
    except:
        print("ERROR>>> 03x00 No such directory")
    try:
        shutil.copy(cpy, dri)
    except:
        print("ERROR>>> 04x00 Command Failure")
```

Problem is that it doesn't end the module if there is no file or directory, only at the finish.

Comment: I reindented the code for you... I hope the way it looks now is what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking that when an exception is raised, Python just stops what it's doing, but that's not quite true. The `except:` block actually catches the exception raised, and is supposed to handle it. After an `except:` block finishes, Python will continue on executing the rest of the code in the file.

In your case, I'd put a `return` after each `print(...)`. That way, after Python prints out an error message, it will also return from the `copy()` function rather than continuing to ask for more input.

Answer (score 0):

**If you *did* want to make the module exit on error...**

Here's how you'd do it.

```
def copy():
    import shutil
    import os
    import sys
    try:
        cpy = input("CMD>>> Name of file(with extension): ")
        open(cpy, "r")
    except:
        sys.exit("ERROR>>> 02x00 No such file")
    try:
        dri = input("CMD>>> Name of Directory: ")
        os.chdir(dri)
        os.chdir("..")
    except:
        sys.exit("ERROR>>> 03x00 No such directory")
    try:
        shutil.copy(cpy, dri)
    except:
        sys.exit("ERROR>>> 04x00 Command Failure")
```

sys.exit(0) (for success) and sys.exit(1) (for failure) are usually used but, since you want to output the error, the above example will output the error string to stderr.

[Here's a link for more info on sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).